# How to change HTML tags by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert the variable x to an existing html-tag.

The image-tag `<img id="Img" src="IMG/.jpg"/>` should get the variable x at the end of its id and its src:

```
        <script>
            var images = <?php echo (json_encode($files));?>
            for(x = 1;x < $images.length-2;x++){
                // <img id="Img"+x src="IMG/"+x+.jpg"/>
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of script tags, the HTML isn't echoed out as in PHP, you have to actually put it somewhere (and add quotes). and `images != $images` etc

Comment: Why don't you just write this all in php?

Comment: I've been trying to find a duplicate to use to close this, but everyone attempting anything similar has done the (very, very little) research needed to find a technique that generates the HTML and then only have specific problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to get the actual `id` and `src`:

```
var path = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]; // That looks for all img-tags in your document and returns an array with all of them. I took the first one (number 0 in the array) - if it is not the first image, change that number.
var imgId = path.id;
var imgSrc = path.src;
```

You wanted to add the variable x to both of them:

```
var newId = imgId + x;
var newSrc = imgSrc + x;
```

Then you can write the new `id` and the new `src` in you image tag:

```
path.setAttribute("id", newId);
path.setAttribute("src", newSrc);
```

So your whole code should look like

```
<script>
    var images = <?php echo (json_encode($files));?>
    for(x = 1;x < $images.length-2;x++){
        //read the id and src
        var path = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        var imgId = path.id;
        var imgSrc = path.src;

        //change them
        var newId = imgId + x;
        var newSrc = imgSrc + x;

        //and write the new id and new src in the image-tag
        path.setAttribute("id", newId);
        path.setAttribute("src", newSrc);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this here should work

```
<script>
        var images = <?php echo (json_encode($files));?>;
        for(x = 1;x < images.length-2;i++){
            document.write('<img id="Img"'+ x + ' src="IMG/"' + x + '.jpg"/>');
        }
</script>
```

im not sure but you may have to add some ' or " befor and after the php code

and i agree with @sublimeobject's comment